# need to move top when click a button using animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hi i want to move my div when i click a button with animation effect so i use .animate . but its not working properly
this is the code i am using

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#box").animate({margin-Top: "300px"});
    });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Animate topdown</button>


<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;"></div>
```

what is the wrong in my code i can't use top instead of margin-top becuse my div  position:relative;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `marginTop` or wrap the property by quotes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      marginTop: "300px"
      // or 
      // "margin-top" : "300px"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Animate topdown</button>


<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just wrap the css property 'margin-top' with single quotes or using the inbuild keyword marginTop

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#box").animate({'margin-Top': "300px"});
    });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Animate topdown</button>


<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;"></div>
```

Comment: No not required! It will work without single quotes too

Comment: @KarthikSivakumar - marginTop is not a string it is inbuilt key variable of jquery animate method its not required single or double quotes. but when we try to write the property in css we need to put single quotes or double quotes to it.